# requiring angular with browserify

Tags: angularjs, browserify

I'm pretty new to angularjs. I'm developing the app with browserify.

When I use `require` with just string, It's working. But When I use it with some string that is combined, it's not working.

I mean `require('./todo')` is working but `var todo = 'todo'; require('./' + todo)` is not.

The problem code index.js is here.

```
   var fs = require('fs');

   var files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
   var controllers = module.exports = {};

   // files.length is 2 and the names are index.js and todo.js
   for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
     var file = files[i];
     if (file !== 'index.js') {
       var fileName = file.split('.')[0];
       var modulePath = './' + fileName;

       // below code is working.
       controllers[fileName] = require('./todo');

       // below code is not working. The error code -> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './todo'
       controllers[fileName] = require(modulePath);
    }
  }
```

What's the problem??

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the fact that browserify is not allow ‘Concat in require’ feature such as require("./fi" + "le") like this. But another bundler such as webpack is allow the feature.